# OpenStreetMap not displaying on my printed maps from QGIS?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, tiles, printing, xyz

I can't figure out the why of when I do a map off my QGIS work while using OpenStreetMap as background map with XYZ Tiles, it simply doesn't get printed while everything else gets printed as expected. It is doing a small freeze when I order for the map to be printed so it seems that there is something not working as expected.

It works just fine with other links however I do want to use OpenStreetMap as it has what I need to use moreover it worked just fine in the past until it started to crash half of the time to finally never work anymore which is confusing.

Am I doing something wrong or it is a bug?

Comment: How large is your print?

Comment: How much RAM is on the computer?

Comment: The computer on which I am using the software has 8 GB of ram, would that be a problem as my file would be too big to process the map ? It is weird because it works just fine with a orthophotoplan basemap provided by the gov of the said region.